# How to display most common emotion over a specific time frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to display the average emotion that is taking place within a 10 second time frame.
The current code will constantly change the most dominate emotion as it happens. Which can be extremely jarring.

```
        import cv2
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        from deepface import DeepFace
        import tensorflow as tf
        import logging
        tf.get_logger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades+'haarcascades_frontalface_default.xml')

        #tries to open webcam
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

        if not cap.isOpened():
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        if not cap.isOpened():
            raise IOError("Could not connect to webcam")

        while true:    
            ret,frame = cap.read
            result = DeepFace.analyze(frame, actions = ['emotions'])
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.1,4)
    
            def most_frequent_emotion(result):
        
        
        
        
    
            for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                cv2.putText(frame,
                           result['dominant_emotion'],
                           (50, 50),
                           font, 3
                           (0, 0, 255),
                           2,
                           cv2.LINE_4)
                cv2.imshow('Original Video', frame)
                if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF = ord('q'):
                    break
    
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: and what is your problem? If you get error message then show it in question. OR maybe you don't know how to calculate `most frequent` ? First you would need some list or dictionary to add emotion in every loop - and when you will have list with emotions then you can count emotions on list and get emotion with the biggest result. Maybe you could even use dictionary `collections.Counter()` for this - and get `most_common()`.

Comment: `True` instead of `true` in line `while True`.

Comment: I wouldn't put `waitKey` and `imshow` inside `for (x,y,w,h) in faces:` because if there will be no faces on frame then `for`-loop will not run and `imshow` will no display frame and `waitKey` will not check keys and you could not stop program with `q`

Comment: you forgot `()` in `cap.read()`

Comment: it is good to check `if frame is None:` or `if ret is True:` because when it don't get frame then it will not raise error but you get error in next function - ie `cvtColor` and you will not know why it can't convert colors. But real problem will be in line `cap.read()`